# Unable to access app engine datastore via Objectify on a local server

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am trying to run an app engine spring project on localhost using eclipse. I am getting the following error in the console.

```
Apr 23, 2018 4:01:04 PM com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials runningOnComputeEngine
WARNING: Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:104)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials.runningOnComputeEngine(ComputeEngineCredentials.java:191)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.tryGetComputeCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:270)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentialsUnsynchronized(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:194)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:112)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:127)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:100)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.defaultCredentials(ServiceOptions.java:298)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.<init>(ServiceOptions.java:272)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreOptions.<init>(DatastoreOptions.java:102)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreOptions.<init>(DatastoreOptions.java:35)
    ...
```

How do I provide credentials to use the datastore in localhost?
I get the following on the console when i access the datastore.

```
2018-04-23 17:22:05.849:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp152005629-14: org.spring.framework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Unauthenticated.
Caused by: 
com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Unauthenticated
```

Comment: This is just a warning -- what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: 2018-04-23 17:22:05.849:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp152005629-14: 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Unauthenticated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objectify v6 uses the Datastore SDK for Google Cloud Platform (which you could think of as GCP's "general purpose" SDK). That SDK makes actual API calls to the cloud service, even when it's being run locally. If you want to run tests/develop against a local datastore, you need to do one of two things.

**Option One**

Instead of using the GCP Datastore SDK, use the App Engine SDK’s Datastore bindings. Objectify has committed in v6 to using the GCP SDK, but v5 used the App Engine SDK. You can downgrade to v5 and everything will "just work".

**Option Two**

If you want to keep using Objectify v6, you need to install an extra gcloud component to run a local datastore emulator and you'll need to set some environment variables. More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator), but the short version goes:

Install and start the datastore emulator:

```
$ gcloud components install cloud-datastore-emulator
$ gcloud beta emulators datastore start
```

Then tell your application where to find it:

```
$ (gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init)
```

Or you can set the relevant env vars manually. On the machine that runs your application, set the environment variables and values as directed by the output of the env-init command. For example:

```
gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8432
export DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=my-project-id
```

Comment: The app is running in local host and only the parts using the datastore is not working. I went through the link you mentioned and it doesn't mention anything about authentication for local host.

Comment: You are using the wrong SDK. You are using the Datastore SDK for Google Cloud Platform (the general SDK). That SDK makes actual API calls to the cloud service even when run locally. You need to use the App Engine SDK’s Datastore bindings.

Comment: I am using the com.googlecode.objectify import paths as specified in https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case you need to install an extra gcloud component to run a local datastore emulator and you'll need to set some environment variables. More details here: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator

Comment: @ArunMuthuraman once again, updated my answer with more details.

Comment: @Venantius Are you able to see your data through the localhost admin page http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/datastore, using option 2?